# Regular expression to replace spaces with dashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to work out what regular expression I would need to take a value and replace spaces with a dash (in Javascript)?

So say if I had North America, it would return me North-America ?

Can I do something like `var foo = bar.replace(' ', '-')` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better to use:

```
var string = "find this and find that".replace(/find/g, "found");
```

to replace all occurrences.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb but how would I do that in my case?

Comment: var foo = bar.replace(/\ /g, '-');

this means, find all regexp matches - regexps in js are surrounded by '/', with option - find all 'g', spaces ('\ ' - escaped) and replace by '-'.

Comment: Why do you think it's better to use this than `bar.replace(' ', '-')`?

Comment: Also worth noting that bar.replace(' ', '-') doesn't replace all occurrences. So the regex version is definitely the best way to go.

Comment: tangens, string.replace() in js replaces only first occurrence.

Comment: @alexander-shvetsov: Thanks, I didn't knew this difference between java and javascript.

Comment: The OP actually asked for "spaces" (plural) to be replaced by "a dash" (singular).  If `North___America` (3 underscores there, representing 3 spaces) should be changed to `North-America` (one dash, as requested), then you'd need a different regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

The best source of information for regular expressions in various languages that I've found is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) (and I linked directly to the Javascript section there).

As for your particular question, yes, you can do something like that.  Did you try it?

```
var before = 'North America';
var after = before.replace(/ +/g, '-')
alert('"' + before + '" becomes "' + after + '"');
```

Use the site I showed you to analyze the regex above.  Note how it replaces *one or more* spaces with a single hyphen, as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

For the most regular expressions, you can do it by testing with the [regular expression tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm).