# Regular Expression - Search and Replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm new to regular expression and have come across a problem.

I want to do a search and replace on a string.

Search for an instance of -- and ' and replace it with - and `, respectively.

Example
Current String: Hi'yo every--body!

Replaced String: Hi`yo every-body!

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Remember that a regular expression is a method for *describing a pattern*.  It's just the "search" part of "search and replace".

You've tagged your question [tag:javascript], so I assume you want to know how to do this in JS, even though your question doesn't specify.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to replace spaces with dashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932499/regular-expression-to-replace-spaces-with-dashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need.

```
"Hi'yo every--body!".replace(/--/g, '-').replace(/'/,'`')
```

Make a function

```
 function andrew_styler(s){return s.replace(/--/g, '-').replace(/'/,'`');}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction!  thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want just replace `--` with `-` use the simplest regexp:

```
var str = "Hi'yo every--body!";
str = str.replace(/--/g, '-');
```

The flag `g` turns the global search on, so that pattern replace all occurances.

Answer (score 1):

@dfsq is correct, regexp is overkill for a couple of simple replaces but for reference.

```
var s = "Hi'yo every--body!";
s = s.replace(/'/g, "`").replace(/\-{2}/g, "-");
```

Comment: +1 But don't forget to use global mathching with `/g`. You regexp will replace only first `--`.